# PHP explode spaces

Tags: php, split, explode

Example of string input:

```
$var = "9999-111 Google";
$var_2 = "9999-222 StackOverflow Web";

I want to get only the postcode and then the address.

$postcode_A = explode(" ", $var);
// postcode[0] returns '9999-111' - postcode[1] returns 'Google'

$postcode_B = explode(" ", $var_2);
// postcode[0] returns '9999-222' - postcode[1] returns 'StackOverflow'
// and I want postcode[1] to return 'StackOverflow Web';
```

How can I achieve that? Thanks.

Comment: RTFM: http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `limit` option of [explode](http://php.net/explode)

```
list($post_code, $name)  = explode(" ", $var_2, 2);
```

Comment: Not working.
`list($post_code, $name) = explode(" ", $var_2, 1);
echo "PC: $postcode---- City: $name<br/>" ;
Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in file.php on line 234` which is: `list($post_code, $name) = explode(" ", $var_2, 1);`

Comment: @user2902515 change the limit to 2 (code updated) as with 1 it returns the entire string as the only element in the array

Answer (score 1):

`explode()` accepts 3rd parameter: `int $limit`

```
list( $postcode, $address ) = explode( ' ', $var, 2 ); // limits number of breaks up to 2
```

Visit official [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) manual page for more examples.

Comment: Not working. list($post_code, $name) = explode(" ", $var_2, 1); echo "PC: $postcode---- City: $name<br/>" ; Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in file.php on line 234 which is: list($post_code, $name) = explode(" ", $var_2, 1);